# How to add actionlistener to a JButton included in node of JTree

Tags: java, swing

There is a `JTree`,and I have rewritten the container of node.The original container of node is `JLabel`,but I have changed it to `JPanel` because the former is not suitable for me.And I have added a `JButton` in `JPanel`.Now I want to monitor the event emitted by this `JButton`.How can I do it?
Here is my code：

```
package com.test.test;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeCellRenderer;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame;
        JPanel contentPanel;

        frame = new JFrame();
        contentPanel = new JPanel();
        frame.setContentPane(contentPanel);

        contentPanel.setLayout(null);

        DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();
        rootNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode());
        JTree tree = new JTree(rootNode);
        tree.setCellRenderer(new Test().new CustomizeNodeRender());
        tree.setToggleClickCount(1);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tree);
        scrollPane.setBounds(0, 0, 320,525);
        contentPanel.add(scrollPane);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    /*
     * 
     * override <code>getTreeCellRendererComponent</code> in <code>DefaultTreeCellRenderer</code> to customize performance of node
     * 
     * */
    class CustomizeNodeRender extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer{

        @Override
        public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
                boolean sel,
                boolean expanded,
                boolean leaf, int row,
                boolean hasFocus){

            super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, sel, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);

            return new NodePanel();

        }

    }

    /*
     * 
     * performance of node
     * 
     * It is a <code>JPanel</code>,and a <code>JButton</code> is included in it.
     * Now we want to monitor the event issued by <code>JButton</code>
     * 
     * */
    class NodePanel extends JPanel{

        public NodePanel(){
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            JButton btnClick = new JButton("click me");
            btnClick.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Thanks for clicking me");
                }

            });
            btnClick.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 20);
            add(btnClick);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: did you read Oracle tutorial - How to use Trees, part, something about TreeCellEditor

Comment: To get a help, you need to provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to copy-paste your code to a *new project* and make sure it compiles and runs before posting it here. When we run your code we should see a tree with 1 or 2 of your new nodes.

Comment: I have rewritten the code in the question.Please see it.It is a example I wrote down just now and the question can be seen in this example.

Comment: And I have read Oracle tutorial,but I haven't found way to solve it.

Comment: I'm sorry,I'm curious about it.I think it is impossible that we can't implement it in java swing.Please help me if you know it.